# Eigenvectors and Eigenvalues of powers of an invertible matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $A$ be an invertible matrix. If $v$ is an eigenvector of $A$, show it is also an eigenvector of $A^k$ for all integers $k$. What are the corresponding eigenvalues?

Comment: Have you tried ?

Comment: yeah I have tried

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: go directly from the definitions.

Answer (score 1):

By definition, $v \neq 0$ is an eigenvector of $A$ with eigenvalue $c$ if and only if then $Av = c v$. Proceed by induction to show $A^k v = c^k v$ for any $k$. If $k = 2$, then $A^2 v = A(Av) = A(cv) = c(Av) = c^2 v$. Suppose $A^{k} v = c^k v$. Then $$A^{k+1} v = A(A^{k}v) = A(c^{k}v) = c^{k} Av = c^{k+1}v.$$ Therefore, it is true for all $k$.